# Possible to check if Application_Start Event fired?

Tags: c#, .net, global-asax

I have some code that I cache on Application_Start Event and then I use it in a master page code behind file.

if my cache object is empty then I log it into my error log saying it was empty. I was thinking though it would be cool to have a check that would say something check the last time Application_Start Event started. I think this would be better than having a hard coded message saying it could possibly be the application_start was not fired.

Is there away to see when the last time Application_Start Event started?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to write to a log file every time application_start fires, for last fire check the last/most recent entry in your log.

Comment: Yes I am already doing this. However someone might not know that the application start has the code that does the caching and needs to be fired(this is the actual case that happened. I gave it to someone they posted it to the server ran it and saw my error message saying the cache was null and asked if I could put more debugging to figure out the reason why). If I had something that could say when they hit the pg that it did has not fired since x minutes and it needs to fire that would be good. Otherwise I guess hard coded msg will have to do.